# Using em and media queries to set relative font size

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a responsive design that can be used across all devices

My css contains the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 400px) {
    html {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

#banner h3 {
    font-size: 3.125em;
    letter-spacing: 0.3125em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: black 0 0.0753125em 0;
}
```

My understanding was that if I set the font-size at html level for different media sizes, then using em will ensure that it will be adjusted accordingly for each element.

So on my desktop my `#banner h3` displays in 50px (16px * 3.125).

However, when I minimize my browser to 700px I was expecting that the h3 would reduce in size, but this is not happening.

This is my website: http://ec2-52-0-228-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code works like charm, see: https://jsfiddle.net/6gLkbvx1/embedded/result/
The error must be something else. please post your html.

Comment: http://pxtoem.com/, 1em = 16px as far as I understand it.

Comment: I've added the URL now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `font-size: 14px;` on your `body`. The `body` is a child element of `html`, that is why the `font-size` of the `html` is overwritten.

`em` refers to the font size of the nearest parent element with a font size, and in your case that is the `body`.

It seems that the body style comes from a wordpress theme or something. If you don't want to change the corresponding css file, you can change your code to overwrite the body:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        font-size: 8px !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        font-size: 12px !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
    body {
        font-size: 16px !important;
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to use `rem` instead of `em`, which is not 100% browser compatible: http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem

Comment: I haven't defined that font-size on the body though, it must be coming from bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work. I had tried setting on body beforehand but I was missing the !important piece. So I guess I learnt the importance of !important as well...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `rem`, not `em`.

A value in `em` is relative to the font-size of the (closest) parent element (or the element's font-size) and if the parent has a fixed font-size (in `px`, for instance) then `em` would be consistent.

But `rem` (root-em) is relative to the value of `font-size` of the root element directly. In HTML, the root element is `<html>`.

```css
#banner h3 {
    font-size: 3.125rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.3125rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: black 0 0.0753125rem 0;
}
```

It's worth mentioning that `rem` is supported in IE9+.

Comment: Also note that there is `font-size: 10px` on `html` within your stylesheet which overrides the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say you should use `rem` unit in order to match the size of the root element (`html` tag).

But a faster way of achieving what you intend to do is to use the `vw` CSS3 unit which is equal to 1% of your viewport width. So you won't have to use media queries at all.